# Monogame Vertex Buffer acting weird

Tags: c#, graphics, monogame

I've exhausted my brain and have come to you for help.

I recently started working on a project to test out Monogame, and quickly ran into an issue, I'm not sure if it's my fault or Mono's.

I have a system where a level has a bunch of static instances added to it (the geometry), then this geometry is saved to a separate class to render it all. The plan was to use vertex and index buffers and use GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives, but this is where i run into issues.

The top image is what it should look like, the bottom one is what it actually looks like:

[image: What it looks like when using array mode]
[image: What it looks like when using buffer mode]

And here is the relevant code. Right now setting the mode to Array works fine, but Buffer is messed up, so i know that the vertices are being added right, and the arrays are right, and the effect is right, only the buffers are wrong.

```
    public void End()
    {
        _vertices = _tempVertices.ToArray();
        _vCount = _vertices.Length;
        _indices = _tempIndices.ToArray();
        _iCount = _indices.Length;

        _vBuffer = new VertexBuffer(_graphics, typeof(VertexPositionColorTexture),
            _vCount, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        _vBuffer.SetData(_vertices, 0, _vCount);

        _iBuffer = new IndexBuffer(_graphics, IndexElementSize.ThirtyTwoBits,
            _iCount, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        _iBuffer.SetData(_indices, 0, _iCount);  

        _tempIndices.Clear();
        _tempVertices.Clear();

        _primitiveCount = _iCount / 3;

        _canDraw = true;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        if (_canDraw)
        {
            switch (DrawMode)
            {
                case Mode.Buffered:
                    _graphics.Indices = _iBuffer;
                    _graphics.SetVertexBuffer(_vBuffer);

                    _graphics.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, _primitiveCount);
                    break;

                case Mode.Array:
                    _graphics.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColorTexture>
                        (PrimitiveType.TriangleList, _vertices, 0, _vCount,
                        _indices, 0, _primitiveCount);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("End must be called before this can be rendered");
    }
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, after hours of trying everything. I may actually be an idiot.

Instead of using indexed drawing, I was simply trying to draw non-indexed primitives.

In the Render() method, i simply changed

```
_graphics.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, _primitiveCount);
```

to:

```
_graphics.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, _vCount, 0, _primitiveCount);
```

And voila, it all works now.

Comment: This had me bashing my head against a wall for hours, too. Thank you for posting an answer to your own question!